# How to generate all derived terms out of a root or lemma word in English using SpaCy or NLTK?

Tags: nlp, nltk, spacy

Is there a function in NLTK or SpaCy that provides all possible terms that can be derived out of a given lemma word? For example: if the lemma is "breath", I need all the derived terms for "breath" such as "breathe", "breathing" etc. If the root word is "eat", I need the terms "eating", "ate", "eaten" and so on.

The .lemma_ attribute in SpaCy and the WordNetLemmatizer() function in NLTK can be used for determining the lemma of a word, but how do I do the reverse task, that is determining all the derived terms out of a given lemma word?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pyinflect` that can be used as a spacy extension. You need to install it first with `pip install pyinflect`. Example of using it:

```
import spacy
import pyinflect

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

verbs = "eating goes touch felt hit sleeping"
doc = nlp(verbs)
for token in doc:
    base = token._.inflect("VB")
    gerund = token._.inflect("VBG")
    past_tense = token._.inflect("VBD")
    past_participle = token._.inflect("VBN")
    print(token.text, "-", base, "-", gerund, "-", past_tense, "-", past_participle)

# Output:
# eating - eat - eating - ate - eaten
# goes - go - going - went - gone
# touch - touch - touching - touched - touched
# felt - feel - feeling - felt - felt
# hit - hit - hitting - hit - hit
# sleeping - sleep - sleeping - slept - slept
```

EDIT: to get the whole list of Tags with a short description, run the following code:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
for label in nlp.get_pipe("tagger").labels:
    print(label, " -- ", spacy.explain(label))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a documentation where I can obtain the list of parameters (such as "VB", "VBG", "VBD" and "VBN") that represent different types of inflections?

Comment: There is a term called Part of Speech Tagging, which includes different forms of standard Parts of Speech. Spacy uses  Penn Treebank POS Tags. Please Google it for now. I'll update my answer when I'm on Computer